# Getting already removed applications in site application list

Tags: c#, server-administration, web-administration

I am getting the list of both removed and present sites under IIS default site.
Below is my code.

```
        ServerManager server = new ServerManager();

        SiteCollection sites = server.Sites;

        foreach (var site in sites)
        {
            var applst = site.Applications;
```

Here in the applst I am getting list of both removed and present applications.
I am not able to understand why it is happening.Does the IIS also caches already removed applications.